# how to specify database name in sqlalchemy Teradata connection string?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, teradata

I am using SQLAlchemy in a Python script. I can run a select query but cannot insert because it doesn't recognize the database name. It seems Teradata doesn't have a schema concept so instead you would say "database some_db".

```
import sqlalchemy
conn_string = 'teradata://' + user + ':' + passw + '@' + host + '/?authentication=LDAP'
eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn_string)
df.to_sql('db_name.my_table', con = eng, if_exists = 'replace', index=False)
```

This gives me an error

```
The user does not have CREATE TABLE access to database (the default DB)
```

But that's because the DB is not specified, which I'm trying to figure out how to do. I'm able to do a select query like this:

```
# execute sql
sql = 'select top 10 * from db_name.some_table'
result = eng.execute(sql)

for x in result:
    print(x)
```

I tried to do this but it didn't help:

```
eng.execute('database db_name')
```

FYI, this script is using sqlalchemy-teradata. I checked the documentation but it doesn't really say much about this:

https://downloads.teradata.com/tools/articles/teradata-sqlalchemy-introduction

I also tried to put the DB into the connection string but it seems to be ignored:

```
conn_string = 'teradata://' + user + ':' + passw + '@' + host + ':1025' + '/database=db_name' + '/?authentication=LDAP'
```

Comment: When you do `df.to_sql('db_name.my_table', con = eng, if_exists = 'replace', index=False)` is `db_name` not `some_db` in this case? What is the db here: `The user does not have CREATE TABLE access to database (some DB name)` is it not `db_name`? It's not clear with all these placeholder names what is happening.

Comment: But you are specifying the db name - `df.to_sql('db_name.my_table', con = eng, if_exists = 'replace', index=False)`.

Comment: I editted to make it more clear. Let's call it db_name. They are the same. It works when I do the select query but not when I try to insert with df.to_sql('db_name.my_table'...)

Comment: Setting default database at the engine level this way connects a session, sets the default database for that session, and disconnects. You would need to set the default in the same session, e.g. `sess=eng.connect()` then `sess.execute('database db_name')` and pass `sess` in place of `eng` to the `to_sql` method.

Answer (score 0):

The *tablename* in `df.to_sql` method is always considered an unqualified name. The "schema" concept is mapped to the Teradata "database" object by the sqlalchemy dialect. So just use the `schema=` parameter:

```
df.to_sql('my_table', schema ='db_name', con = eng, if_exists = 'replace', index=False)
```

Comment: By the way, better to use the current / supported _teradatasqlalchemy_ module (and _teradatasql_ dialect) for new work versus _sqlalchemy-teradata_ and _teradata_ dialect; but answer would be the same except URL parameter `authentication=LDAP` becomes `logmech=LDAP`